# Laravel REST API - infinite loop

Tags: php, laravel, rest, authentication, oauth

I am building a REST user-microservice using Laravel 5.5 + Passport. 
I am using the standard Passport::routes(), but I have had to modify the Auth::routes in order to make them return JSON responses, and to make them work with Passport.

I have added the following lines to my routes/web.php file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    $this->post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
});
```

This allows me to POST https://myapi/logout

- If I make the call with the header "Authorization => Bearer TOKEN", I get a successful logout response.
- If I provide no header at all, I get a "not authenticated" message (which is good)
- However, if I provide the header with a revoked token, I get a recursive deadloop of the function: `Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard->user()` (it keeps calling itself recursively until stack-overflow)

This is all done in the `auth:api` middleware, my logout code is not reached, but my LoginController constructor **is** called. Constructor code:

```
public function __construct(Application $app)
    {
        $this->apiConsumer = $app->make('apiconsumer');

        $this->middleware('guest')
             ->except('logout');
    }
```

I'm struggling to understand if it's my code causing this issue, or some combination of Laravel + passport + auth.

My first thought was that the auth:api middleware fails to authenticate the user, and as a result redirects the user to /home, where for some reason it's triggered again, recursively. But if that was the case, why would it work correctly with no header?

My current thinking is that the token in question **does** exist in the database, but Laravel is failing to figure out that it's revoked.

Any suggestions appreciated,

Comment: Have you tried removing the logout route and just register `passport` routes as stated in the docs in `AuthServiceProvider.php` in the `boot()` method by typing `Passport::routes();`?

Comment: I haven't, would I then manually re-implement the auth logout method?

Comment: are you using this application in locally?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer (if not *the* answer) after a lot of research. It appears this is a Laravel bug (https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/440). The solution is to add OAuthServerException to the $dontReport array in app/Exceptions/Handler.php:

```
class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    protected $dontReport = [
       ...
        \League\OAuth2\Server\Exception\OAuthServerException::class,
    ];
}
```

This will avoid trying to log user information, thereby avoid the deadloop.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this in localhost. in my case, I have used xampp server and facing this issue 
after creating a virtual host like "testlarave.test" then solve the error